# OpenCV 2.2 project settings

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to do a project with OpenCV 2.2. I've successfully compiled OpenCV and QT (so I can get support for opengl). All of the samples work. However, when I try to create my own project from scratch and link against the opencv libs the camera examples give me a black screen. The exact same code compiles but when the application runs it somehow fails. The webcam led is on but nothing is shown in the window.

Normally the console window would show something like this (when the program works correctly):

press q or esc to quit
init done
opengl support available

In my own project it just shows:
press q or esc to quit

Could something be the matter with the initialization? Also I am giving my application

HAVE_VIDEOINPUT
HAVE_DSHOW
HAVE_QT
HAVE_QT_OPENGL
HAVE_CONFIG_H

definitions through the Visual Studio project properties options. I am using Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 64 bits.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to patch OpenCV 2.2 to work correctly with webcams in windows.

See http://dissipatedheat.com/2011/04/24/opencv-ile-webcam-goruntusu-isleme/, it is in Turkish, you can try google translate.